# Vertically Align rotated list items containing long text

Tags: css

I've created a list of items that are rotated. Everything is rolling except for long strings... For an unknown reason, the "long items" gets pushed below the green alignment stroke.

[image: alignment problem here with long strings]

I may see 2 cases here depending on whether the string contains spaces or not (item B vs item C.

I've tried to play with vertical-align, then flexbox without success. if you have ideas, I'll take them gracefully.

Thank you so much.

```css
ol {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 221);
}

li:last-child::before {
  display: none;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -75px;
  left: -25px;
  color: #000;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


li.checked {
  background-color: #27a2b8;
  border-color: rgb(20, 25, 10);
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.checkbox>input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.checkbox>svg>circle {
  stroke-width: 6px;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg {
  background-color: rgb(0, 175, 245);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg>path {
  stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item"><span class="info s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ">Item A is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemA">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item B is really too long</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item-c-is-also-really-too-long-too</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemC">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">Item c is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox" name="itemD">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap` on your `li span`, this should fix it.

Here is the modified snippet:

```css
ol {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 221);
}

li:last-child::before {
  display: none;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -75px;
  left: -25px;
  color: #000;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


li.checked {
  background-color: #27a2b8;
  border-color: rgb(20, 25, 10);
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.checkbox>input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.checkbox>svg>circle {
  stroke-width: 6px;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg {
  background-color: rgb(0, 175, 245);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg>path {
  stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item"><span class="info s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ">Item A is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemA">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item B is really too long</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item-c-is-also-really-too-long-too</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemC">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">Item c is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox" name="itemD">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the html and css file and reached this result. Hopefully it benefits your business. I put the text in a div and added the p tag. I made some minor changes in css and used `overflow-wrap:break-word`

```css
ol {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 221);
}

li:last-child::before {
  display: none;
}

li p {
  top: -100px;
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li span {
  top: -77px;
  left: -22px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li.checked {
  background-color: #27a2b8;
  border-color: rgb(20, 25, 10);
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.checkbox > input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.checkbox > svg > circle {
  stroke-width: 6px;
}

.checkbox .checked > svg {
  background-color: rgb(0, 175, 245);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .checked > svg > path {
  stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ol>
            <li class="item">
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    <span style="padding:-3px;">Item A is OK</span>
                    <div>
                        <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                                <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item checked">
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    <p>B is really too long</p>
                    <div>
                        <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                                <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item checked">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <p>Item-C-is-also-really-too-long-too</p>
                    <div>
                        <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                                <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    <span>Item D is OK</span>
                    <div>
                        <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                                <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one more solution, see your updated code.
It work with left aligned text and fixed text width.

[You can also check Codepen.io example.](https://codepen.io/yaroslav-trach/pen/RwjNveM)

```css
:root {
  --ol-gap-size: 20px;
}

ol {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  column-gap: var(--ol-gap-size);
}

li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
  border-radius: 50%;
/*   display: inline-block; */
/*   margin-right: 20px; */
/*   box-sizing: content-box; */
}

li:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(var(--ol-gap-size) + 5px);
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 221);
}

/* li:last-child::before {
  display: none;
} */

/* li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
} */

li span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) rotate(-70deg);
  transform-origin: calc(var(--ol-gap-size) * -1) center;
  
  /*   top: -75px; */
  /*   left: -25px; */
  /*   transform: rotate(-70deg); */
}


li.checked {
  background-color: #27a2b8;
  border-color: rgb(20, 25, 10);
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.checkbox>input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.checkbox>svg>circle {
  stroke-width: 6px;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg {
  background-color: rgb(0, 175, 245);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .checked>svg>path {
  stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item"><span class="info s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ">Item A is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemA">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item B is really too long</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemB">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item checked">
    <span class="title">Item-c-is-also-really-too-long-too</span>
    <div class="checkbox checked" name="itemC">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">Item c is OK</span>
    <div class="checkbox" name="itemD">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M6.5 12.5l4 4 8-8" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="s-QW0kY0-XRkIZ"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```